# How to change value of cdata inside a .xml file and then again save it using php

Tags: php, xml, dom, cdata

i want to just change ABCD written inside cdata of data.xml file with a new value held by $change by php. i am able to get all cdata value using the following code but don't know how to change and save it.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('data.xml');
$destinations = $doc->getElementsByTagName("text");
foreach ($destinations as $destination) {
    foreach($destination->childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child->nodeType == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {
            echo $child->textContent . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**my data.xml file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data displayWidth="" displayHeight="" frameRate="" fontLibs="assets/fonts/Sansation_Regular.swf">
    <preloader type="snowflake" size="40" color="0xffffff" shapeType="circle" shapeSize="16" numShapes="8"/>
        <flipCard openingDuration="2" openCardZ="400" tweenMethod="easeOut" tweenType="Back">
            <video videoPath="video.MP4" frontImage="assets/christmas/front.jpg" videoPoster="assets/christmas/videoPoster.jpg" videoFrame="assets/christmas/videoFrame.png" bufferTime="10" loopVideo="true"/>
            <flips backImage="assets/christmas/back.jpg" backColor="0x808080">

            <flip isText="true" xPos="600" yPos="470" openDelay="8" openDuration="2" tweenMethod="easeOut" tweenType="Elastic" action="link" url="http://activeden.net/">
                <text id="name" font="Sansation_Regular" embedFonts="true" size="40" color="0x802020"><![CDATA[ABCD]]></text>
            </flip>

            <flip isText="true" xPos="300" yPos="30" openDelay="2" openDuration="2" tweenMethod="easeOut" tweenType="Elastic">
                <text font="Sansation_Regular" embedFonts="true" size="80" color="0x202020"><![CDATA[HAPPY]]></text>
            </flip>
        </flips>
    </flipCard>
</data>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You change the text inside a CDATA section by setting the `nodeValue` of that CDATA node ([**DOMCdataSection** in PHP](http://php.net/class.domcdatasection)):

```
$child->nodeValue = $change;
```

Output (excerpt & simplified):

```
    ...
        <flip isText="true" xPos="600" yPos="470" openDelay="8" openDuration="2" tweenMethod="easeOut" tweenType="Elastic" action="link" url="http://activeden.net/">
            <text id="name" ... color="0x802020"><![CDATA[changed ABCD]]></text>
        </flip>

        <flip isText="true" xPos="300" yPos="30" openDelay="2" openDuration="2" tweenMethod="easeOut" tweenType="Elastic">
            <text font="Sansation_Regular" ... ><![CDATA[changed HAPPY]]></text>
        </flip>

    ...
```

---

For your second question you have on how to save the document: The method to save the XML document is [`DOMDocument::save`](http://php.net/domdocument.save):

```
$filename = '/path/to/file.xml';
$doc->save($filename);
```

Comment: yes your code it working but adding -new at last but i want to replace ABCD with new value not adding -new at last.

Comment: @shubhjaiswal: Naturally that was only ***exemplary***, the more important part is that you set the field named ***nodeValue*** of the ***DOMCdataSection*** object you have in `$child` to the *string* value of your wish and dreams. E.g. `$change`, see as well the edited answer which now refers to that variable namely, just in case you still have problems to understand how the assignment ("setting") with a different expression (in your case the `$change` variable) would look like. Let me know if you still have troubles.

Comment: now its working fine after your second edit. but its changing both cdata value how to change only one(abcd).


`code`
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$xml='data.xml';
$doc->load($xml);
$destinations = $doc->getElementsByTagName("text");
foreach ($destinations as $destination) {
    foreach($destination->childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child->nodeType == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {
            echo $child->textContent . "<br/>";
   $child->nodeValue = "new value";
        }
    }
}
$doc->save($xml);
?>

Comment: @shubh jaiswal: Well, naturally it changes as many or little CDATA nodes as you write down in your code to change - and also to the values you command it to change. Change the commands if you're not yet confident the way it works to the right order. I assume you can benefit from learning about XPath to query only the one element you want to change. However what you've asked for - how to change the text of a CData node - is already answered completely and I also already commented back effectively on your first comment. There is a reason why you should keep your questions concrete on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @Hakre is correct. just want to update final working code because following code will only update my ABCD value not all.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$xml='data.xml';
$doc->load($xml);
$destinations = $doc->getElementsByTagName("text");
foreach ($destinations as $destination) {
    foreach($destination->childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child->nodeType == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {
            echo $child->textContent . "<br/>";
            $child->nodeValue = "new value";
        }
    }break;
}
$doc->save($xml);
?>
```

Comment: Looks sane. You can also move the `break` directly after the part where you're done, that is after the assignment of the new value: `$child->nodeValue = "new value";` (newline) `break;`